# ¿Por qué QueryString no recibe el método POST?

Tags: asp.net, post, querystring

Estoy intentando enviar las variables de mi formulario por método POST en ASP.NET (C#); cuando envío por GET, la función QueryString sí recibe la variable y la puedo imprimir, pero con el método POST solo estoy recibiendo la variable como nula.

FORMULARIO (Default.aspx)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="post_get.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server" action="Recieve.aspx" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Página que Recibe (Recieve.aspx)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        string str = Request.QueryString["txt1"];
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Hola: " + str + "');", true);
    }
}
```

De antemano, les agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando envías un formulario de tipo `GET` los atributos van en el `QueryString` pero cuando los envías en un `POST` los datos van en el `body`. Para acceder a tus datos en un request de tipo `POST` puedes hacerlo así:

```
Request.Form["txt1"];
```

Ahora para simplificar puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
Request["txt1"];
```

la línea de código anterior te debería funcionar tanto para un request de tipo GET como de tipo POST

> To access data from the QueryString, Form, Cookies, or ServerVariables
>   collections, you can write Request["key"]

[MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Muchas gracias, hermano! Me sirvió mucho!

Comment: @EduardoSantillán si te ha funcionado considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada ;)

Comment: Es cierto, listo.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que acceder al formulario no al query string :

```
Request.Form["key"]
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias, hermano! Me sirvió!